# terminology for a "forward flow" type of random digraph

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, terminology, random-graphs

I am trying to find a characterization of the probability that vertex $1$ is connected to an arbitrary large vertex $N$ in a random digraph.

The difference from typical random digraphs is that if $(i,j)$ is an edge then $i < j$, i.e., edges can only go from lower indexed vertex to higher indexed vertex.

Is there a term for this type of digraph? And is there any references anyone can suggest?

Thank you very much for any help you can offer.

Comment: Sounds similar to a [Hasse Diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram) though that one is not a digraph, which doesn't seem to matter at all to answer your question

Comment: I tseems you're implying that your vertex 1 is lower than that large vertex N, but then wouldn't the probability be 100%? Since you said there's an edge *if and only if* $i < j$. One of the edits changed your "=> (only if) to "if and only if"

Comment: @Emisor I think he means if $i<j$ then there will be an edge with probability $p$. He is working on random graphs...

Comment: no. I actually meant only if since not all ij (for i<j) may be an edge.

Comment: @gt6989b yeah then that edit screwed up since there's sort of a contradiction there. Be sure to read all edit requests before accepting them, things like this can happen

Comment: Sorry. Clicked the wrong button and ended up approving the edit earlier. Now the question goes back to being non-trivial, I think.

Comment: @Emisor: I think it does matter that it's a digraph.  For instance, if there are edges $(1, 3)$ and $(2, 3)$, then $1$ and $2$ are connected in the undirected graph, but not connected in the digraph.

Comment: Yes. That is correct. Every paths in this graph will have vertices which are increasing. Maybe I should change the word "graph" to "digraph" everywhere in the question?

Comment: @BrianTung i meant that the Hasse Diagram could've been a digraph and it'd be the same. Actually, it'd make more sense to me if it was, and i don't even know why it isnt